# Timer count throughout the game in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I am creating a game application in which I need to set timer of 2 minutes throughout the app screens in objective c.

I am creating it in viewDidLoad but it is creating a new instance every-time the view loads.

Here is the code which I am using :

```
@interface SomeViewController ()
{
    int timerCounter;
     NSTimer *timer;   
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timerLbl;

@end

@implementation SomeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self startCountdown];
}


- (void)startCountdown
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(countdownTimer:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
}

- (void)countdownTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    timerCounter--;

    int minutes = timerCounter / 60;
    int seconds = timerCounter % 60;

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", minutes];
    NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", seconds];

    NSString *timeTotal = [string stringByAppendingString:@":"];
    NSString *timeTotal2 = [timeTotal stringByAppendingString:string2];

    _timerLbl.text = timeTotal2;
    if (timerCounter <= 0) {
        [timer invalidate];   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invalidate it whenever the VC deallocates

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [timer invalidate];
}
```

//

The second VC may look like this

```
#import "ggViewController.h"
NSInteger timerCounter = 120;     // declared global to hold the value 
@interface ggViewController ()
{
    NSTimer*timer;
}
@end

@implementation ggViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

   // instead of using selector use this inline callback
  timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 repeats:true block:^(NSTimer * timer) {

     timerCounter--;

     int minutes = timerCounter / 60;
     int seconds = timerCounter % 60;

     NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", minutes];
     NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", seconds];

     NSString *timeTotal = [string stringByAppendingString:@":"];
     NSString *timeTotal2 = [timeTotal stringByAppendingString:string2];

     _timerLbl.text = timeTotal2;
      if (timerCounter <= 0) {
          [timer invalidate];   
         }
    }];

}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [timer invalidate];
}


- (IBAction)gg:(id)sender {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
}
@end
```

Comment: I need it running even when I get back to same screen

Comment: then use dealloc

Comment: Let me expalin the scenerio, I add up a timer of 2 mins when game starts, I answer a quesition in 10 secs , now when I come back to same screen the timer should not be invalidated (it must be continued till it becomes 0)

Comment: this will invalidate the timer when the vc is about to be released , try it first

Comment: Used it, but it refreshes timer again to 2:00

Comment: how do you comeback ?? you use Unwindsegue / pop

Comment: I have used pop

Comment: if viewDidLoad is called when you come back , then your return is incorrect and it's creation of a another instance ' , add a log inside it and check

Comment: share how you perform the present of the next Vc and how do you perform the pop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180374/discussion-between-ios-and-sh-khan).